# unable to connect to broadband connection with two LAN card

Tags: networking, internet

I have installed Ubuntu on my system, which has two LAN card. One of the LAN card is not working. But the other do work. I have tried configuring the internet connection but failed.

Comment: Please describe your situation with more details. Did you use the network-manager (network icon)? Does it display two, one or zero networks? Does it change if you plug in the network cable. If you are familiar with the terminal, look at the output from `ifconfig -a`. This lists all network interfaces, `eth0` and `eth1` are the first two LAN connections. `lo` is a dummy network for connections to localhost.

Comment: first of all, i am new to ubuntu, and just installed Ubuntu today(dual boot with windows XP). I got two network eth0 and eth1, in windows i connect to my broadband using login name and password. But in Ubuntu i dont know how to. i tried "sudo pppoeconf" but coudnt figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, I assume, you want to setup a PPPoE connection. This is a method used by some broadband modems to connect a single computer to the internet. You have already connected modem and computer via ethernet and the method works on Windows. You want to know how to do the same with Ubuntu. The fact the you have two network cards could make it harder to get the configuration right? Did I get this?

On modern versions of Ubuntu all network connections are handles by the network-manager. You can access the network manager via its icon (two computers) in the status bar. You can right-click the icon and select "edit connections ..." or similar. This opens a dialog box. The last tab in this dialog reads "DSL" or "Broadband" or similar. Here, click the  "Add + " button and enter username + password for your broadband connection.

This is the standard method that you should try first. At the moment, I do not know, how Ubuntu decides which network interface to use. Possible, it will scan all of them for a PPPoE modem.

Comment: i tried this, but didnt work.

Comment: @Harish Kurup You could probably get better help, if you rewrote your question to be more specific: Something like "How to setup PPPoE over one out of two eth interfaces". List specifically, what you have tried and try to get some more information about your system? Is the modem connected to eth0 or eth1?